# Density in R plot

Tags: plot

I am trying to plot the density of the gamma distribution.

```
x<-seq(0,10000,length.out = 1000)
plot(density(rgamma(1000,shape = 7,scale = 120)))
plot(dgamma(x,shape=7,scale=120),col="red")
```

But, I don't understand why both plots are totally different.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't supply `x` in the final call, the `x` coordinates defaulted to the indices 1,2,3,...1000 of the vector `dgamma(x,shape=7,scale=120)` rather than the intended 0,10,20,....

If you do:

```
x<-seq(0,10000,length.out = 1000)
plot(density(rgamma(1000,shape = 7,scale = 120)))
points(x,dgamma(x,shape=7,scale=120),type = "l", col="red")
```

Then the graph is:

[image]